# Appium : Could not pre-launch appium: Error: Could not find a device to launch. You requested 'iPhone (9.1 Simulator)'

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, appium

When I am running appium and setting the simulator as 8.3 and Iphone 5s it is giving as below error.
When I launch app via Xcode ( Compile and run) it is able to run the apps on 8.3 / 9.0/9.1 which means I have all the Simulators then why Appium is giving this error to me ?

Could not pre-launch appium: Error: Could not find a device to launch. You requested 'iPhone (9.1 Simulator)', but the available devices were: ["iPad 2 (9.1) [82A1899B-132B-41B0-9804-957278EDEF56]","iPad Air (9.1) [8952F210-1E29-48E0-88F7-0AEA1FDA57A8]","iPad Air 2 (9.1) [4E2A944D-A98C-473A-9E2E-8A234A80FC1C]","iPad Pro (9.1) [F6A8E847-7C1E-448F-884C-583BC2303EA9]","iPad Retina (9.1) [EE7B683F-4964-44C6-B5CB-D63547B3D4B5]","iPhone 4s (9.1) [B6BBC191-9DF8-4E8B-BE70-9483115E03E3]","iPhone 5 (9.1) [57A5EF1C-620E-4E76-B295-FF64509DF0B9]","iPhone 5s (9.1) [F6ED93CF-C4A1-4B58-B311-795EDBF06A81]","iPhone 6 (9.1) [BF14D012-4ED3-4FCC-B1A3-F6959F4A1E24]","iPhone 6 Plus (9.1) [807653E8-70B6-43DB-A949-CAA301B5A77D]","iPhone 6s (9.1) [2E7B8274-37C5-49B8-99E8-CFD8C4FA398D]","iPhone 6s (9.1) + Apple Watch - 38mm (2.0) [602E351F-71A6-48BF-BF39-66081AF6A628]","iPhone 6s Plus (9.1) [8B475256-929B-49AC-B4AF-503286DD70AE]","iPhone 6s Plus (9.1) + Apple Watch - 42mm (2.0) [43DFF555-6CD8-43BE-93C7-5749DDAB3DAD]"]

Comment: have you tried running on real device? so that you can pin point the issue. If it works on real device you 'll know if it's simulator issue or appium issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open Window > Devices from the menu bar when Xcode is open. There, go search for the mentioned simulators and delete them. Readd 'em and then try it again. It seems like Xcode messed something up with its simulators.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new capability and pass your device udid:

```
capabilities.setCapability("udid", "deviceudid");
```